# How to iterate over a selector?

Tags: angular

I am creating a copy of whatsappweb and I am in the component of listing all the latest messages from friends of the "user main".

I always insert all selector results from app.component, but this time I have to insert this logic into my dumb component, as it needs a user's id to be able to render the information.

And I fell into a curiosity, which is:

I have a list of users and I need to iterate under it to get the id of each user and be able to intersect the data to get the latest messages etc.

How can I do this?

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of userFriends">
        <app-avatar [isBig]="true" [src]="user.avatar" [alt]="user.full_name"></app-avatar>
        <app-userfriend-last-messages-container
            [isNewLastMessage]="false"
            [username]="user.full_name"
            [lastmessage]="chatSelectorsService.getLastFriendMessage(userId).id | async"
        ></app-userfriend-last-messages-container>
        <app-userfriend-last-messages-information-container
            [isNewLastMessage]="false"
            [lastMessageTime]="chatSelectorsService.getLastFriendMessage(userId).time | async"
            [lastMessageAmount]="9"
        ></app-userfriend-last-messages-information-container>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**TS:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-last-messages-list',
    templateUrl: './last-messages-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./last-messages-list.component.scss'],
})
export class LastMessagesListComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() userFriends: IUser[];
    @Input() chatLastMessages: IChatMessage[];

    constructor(readonly chatSelectorsService: ChatSelectorsService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question or problem you're facing?

Comment: In this way I did not show any results in the selector.

Comment: `chatSelectorsService.getLastFriendMessage(userId).id | async` is `id` really async?

Comment: You probably want`(chatSelectorsService.getLastFriendMessage(userId) | async).id` same for `time` below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to keep just 1 `async` pipe in the template that fetches all information it needs, your template could be

```html
<ul *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
    <li *ngFor="let user of data.userFriends">
        <app-avatar [isBig]="true" [src]="user.avatar" [alt]="user.full_name"></app-avatar>
        <app-userfriend-last-messages-container
            [isNewLastMessage]="false"
            [username]="user.full_name"
            [lastmessage]="user.lastmessage"
        ></app-userfriend-last-messages-container>
        <app-userfriend-last-messages-information-container
            [isNewLastMessage]="false"
            [lastMessageTime]="user.lastMessageTime"
            [lastMessageAmount]="9"
        ></app-userfriend-last-messages-information-container>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in your component you should add `data$` that aggregates all data you need for the template.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-last-messages-list',
    templateUrl: './last-messages-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./last-messages-list.component.scss'],
})
export class LastMessagesListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() userFriends: IUser[];
    @Input() chatLastMessages: IChatMessage[];

    // internal subject to notify on changes of userFriends
    protected userFriends$ = new Subject();

    // our stream that provides data for the template asynchronously.
    public readonly data$ = this.userFriends$.pipe(
        filter(users => Array.isArray(users)),
        switchMap(users => {
            const data = [];
            for (const user of users) {
                data.push(chatSelectorsService.getLastFriendMessage(user.id).pipe(
                    map(lastMessage => ({
                        ...user,
                        lastmessage: lastMessage ? lastMessage.id : undefined,
                        lastMessageTime: lastMessage ? lastMessage.time : undefined,
                    })),
                ));
            }
            return combineLatest(data);
        }),
        map(userFriends => ({userFriends})),
    );

    constructor(readonly chatSelectorsService: ChatSelectorsService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.userFriends$.next(this.userFriends);
    }

    // listening on changes of the input.
    public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (changes.userFriends && changes.userFriends.currentValue !== changes.userFriends.previousValue) {
            this.userFriends$.next(changes.userFriends.currentValue);
        }
    }
}
```